# make wordpress log errors in apache log file

Tags: 404-error

I need to log 404 errors and wp-login failed attempts on wordpress site. Unfortunately it natively handles everything and doesn't write to apache log file.

I tried this:
404.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="post-0" class="post error404 not-found">
    <h1><?php _e('Page Not Found', "magazine-basic"); ?></h1>
    <div class="storycontent">
        <p><?php _e('The page you requested could not be found.', "magazine-basic"); ?></p>
    </div><!-- .storycontent -->
</div><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php
error_log("File does not exist: " . rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], "/") . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0);
get_footer();
?>
```

Functions.php

```
// Log login errors to Apache error log
add_action('wp_login_failed', 'log_wp_login_fail'); // hook failed login

function log_wp_login_fail($username) {
    error_log("WP login failed for username: $username");
}
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick. Any thoughts ideas how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I use a separate error-log-file for WordPress that i add to wp-config.php like this:

**Step 1: Create a log file**

Create an empty file called “php-errors.log”. This file will serve as your site’s PHP error log. Your server will need write access to this file, so make sure to set the appropriate permissions.

**Step 2: Add the magic code**

Add this to wp-config.php after `That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging.`

```
// log php errors
@ini_set('log_errors','On'); // enable or disable php error logging (use 'On' or 'Off')
@ini_set('display_errors','Off'); // enable or disable public display of errors (use 'On' or 'Off')
@ini_set('error_log','/home/path/logs/php-errors.log'); // path to server-writable log file
```

Once in place, edit the third line with the absolute directory path to the php-errors.log file created in the first step. Upload to your server and call it done. All PHP errors will now be logged to your php-errors.log file, thereby enabling you to monitor and resolve errors as quickly as possible.

This trick is from [diggwp](http://digwp.com/2009/07/monitor-php-errors-wordpress/). and there you can read more about solutions to handle errors in WordPress.

Comment: Hi thanks. This is useful, but my question is specific to 404 errors and failed login attempts I'm configuring fail2ban to block hacking attempts. So php errors won't do me any good.